# Render non english characters in asciidoctor-pdf

Tags: ruby, pdf, encoding, asciidoctor

I am trying to write documentation with asciidoctor-pdf and I need to use characters like : ă,â,î,ş,ţ. The pdf output is rendered but the mentioned characters are rendered empty. I am not sure how to handle the issue.

For example:

I wrote this code:

```
= Document Title
Doc Writer <doc@example.com>
:doctype: book
:source-highlighter: coderay
:listing-caption: Listing
// Uncomment next line to set page size (default is Letter)
//:pdf-page-size: A4

A simple http://asciidoc.org[AsciiDoc] document.

== Introducţie

A paragraph followed by a simple list with square bullets.
```

And the result was the word Introducţie rendered as Introduc ie and finally the error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/pdf-core-0.2.5/lib/pdf/core/pdf_object.rb:55: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
```

- Can be a system encoding configuration problem?
- Do I need to set different encoding configuration in ruby?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a new version of asciidoctor-pdf in the works, it very well may fix your problems. You could try building HEAD and see if the problem persists. If it does, please create a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to be sure, you can always use the decimal entity references form. For the latin small Letter T with cedilla it is: `&#355;`

Check this table for the complete list:
[List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

In addition, if you want to use this special char in a title, there was an issue with it:
[Section id with characters outside of Windows-1252 encoding causes warning](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/308)

It seems to be fixed now, but I did not verify it.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways to write such special characters in titles is to declare them in preamble of your `asciidoc` document, for example,

`:t-cedil: &#x00163;`

and to call it in the main text

```
== pass:normal[Test-{t-cedil}]
```

So your title will look like

**Test-ţ**